# Fibonacci function in Apex

Tags: apex

Is there any documentation about the Fibonacci function present pre-defined in Apex? I tried to find any doc but I was not able to.

This query came as I was working on some Apex practice problems and this problem came up

> The first two numbers in the Fibonacci sequence are 1 & 1, and all other
> numbers in the sequence are defined as the sum of the last two
> Fibonacci numbers. The first 10 numbers in the Fibonacci sequence are
> 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, and 55.
>
> Implement the function **nThFibonacciNumber** that takes as input an Integer n and
> returns the nth Fibonacci number. Assume that n will always be greater
> than 0. Below are the examples
>
> fibonacci(1) = 1
>
> fibonacci(2) = 1
>
> fibonacci(5) = 5

I looked up on ChatGPT as I was not able to do it and ChatGPT gave the solution as

```
public Integer nThFibonacciNumber(Integer n) {
    if (n == 1 || n == 2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return fibonacci(n - 1) + fibonacci(n - 2);
    }
}
```

And in the explanation it mentioned, "You can implement the Fibonacci function in Apex recursively..."

Comment: If you can't find it in [the documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dev_guide.htm), then it is not available.  ChatGPT needs to RTFM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no "serious" languages I know of that implement a default Fibonacci number function, especially not Apex. The point of such an algorithm in any language is to learn about recursion in a given language. As ChatGPT said, "you can implement the Fibonacci function in Apex recursively..." You are expected to implement your own function. In this case, ChatGPT hallucinated by giving you the wrong method name. It should have said:

```
public Integer nThFibonacciNumber(Integer n) {
    if (n == 1 || n == 2) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return nThFibonacciNumber(n - 1) + nThFibonacciNumber(n - 2);
    }
}
```

Though I probably would have written:

```
Integer nThFibonacciNumber(Integer n) {
    if(n == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if(n == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    return nThFibonacciNumber(n-1) + nThFibonacciNumber(n-2);
}
```

Comment: The first piece of code that you gave is working correctly and giving the correct output. However, I am not able to understand how it is calculating the value. I mean let's say if I give the value as n=10, then how is it able to find that n-1 = 34 and n-2= 21 and then adding it up to give the value as 55.

Comment: @Ganit fac(10) calls fac(9) + fac(8), fac(9) calls fac(8) + fac(7), fac(8) calls fac(7) + fac(6), etc, calling the left side first, which recurses all the way down to fac(2) which returns fac(1) + fac(0). Then, the right side of each addition is called. In this way, it goes up and down the stack, adding each value together to accumulate the final value. If you add a debug statement to your code, you should understand it better.

Comment: out of curiosity: wouldn't it be better to have a map variable that stores all previously calculated values to avoid recursion?

Comment: @Novarg Yes, but that's not the point here. It's about teaching recursion. However, even a map isn't the best solution. Either store the precomputed values as a lookup table: `List<Integer> values = new List<Integer> { 0, 1, 1, 2, 3 ...}` or compute them initially just once: `Integer[] numbers = new Integer[] { 0, 1 }; for(Integer index = 2; index < 47; index++) { numbers.add(numbers[index-1]+numbers[index-2]); }`. Note that after fib(47), the numbers no longer fit in a 32-bit signed Integer, so it's faster just to store all the values initially.

Comment: @Novarg or a more heap-friendly version: `Integer[] values = new Integer[47]; values[0] = 0; values[1] = 1; for(Integer index = 2; index < 47; index++) { values[index] = values[index - 1] + values[index - 2]; }` (it preallocates the list's size, avoiding resizing the list repeatedly).